# Newtonsoft not found by batch file only

Tags: c#, visual-studio

My environment is Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition on Windows 10.
I have a solution named MyWebApi inside MyWebApi folder which uses Newtonsoft. When I open the solution in Visual Studio and build the solution, it build successfully. Now I am trying to build the solution outside of Visual Studio via a batch file. So I create a batch file with this line:

```
dotnet build MyWebApi\MyWebApi.sln --configuration Debug
```

Then open PowerShell and run the batch file. But I get an error message:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be
> found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

So on the same computer, Visual Studio can find the 'Newtonsoft' but the batch file cannot? How can I solve this issue?

The batch file only has 1 line:

```
dotnet build MyWebApi\MyWebApi.sln --configuration Debug
```

Not sure why someone voted that this question need more clarity? The batch file contains just 1 line and I am running it from PowerShell. I have also tried running it from PowerShell as an Administrator but still the same error message.

Comment: What happens if you try `dotnet restore` before `dotnet build`?

Comment: @aybe I ran `dotnet restore MyWebApi\MyWebApi.sln` and it ran successfully. Then I ran `dotnet build MyWebApi\MyWebApi.sln --configuration Debug` and it again give me the same error message

Comment: If it works when tried manually under developer command prompt then your batch may be doing something funky, you should post the batch file in your question.

Comment: @aybe the batch file only has 1 line `dotnet build MyWebApi\MyWebApi.sln --configuration Debug`

Comment: Does it work under developer command prompt?

Comment: no it did not work